# SVG Opera 12 ctrl zoom

Tags: svg, opera

If you click on svg with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> in Opera 12, svg will zoom in. How could I prevent this behaviour?
I need to click on svg with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> without zooming it.

[SVG example](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-SVG11-20110816/images/shapes/rect01.svg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable UA zooming and panning by using the [`zoomAndPan`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#ZoomAndPanAttribute) attribute on the root <svg> element.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="12cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" zoomAndPan="disable">
  <desc>Example rect01 - rectangle with sharp corners</desc>

  <!-- Show outline of canvas using 'rect' element -->
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="1198" height="398"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"/>

  <rect x="400" y="100" width="400" height="200"
        fill="yellow" stroke="navy" stroke-width="10"  />
</svg>
```